# Rspec Stub Fetched Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

How does one stub a model that gets fetched in the controller?

Example:

```
# Model Spec
it 'does something' do
  allow(model).to receive(:value).and_return 100
  model2 = FactoryGirl.create :model
  allow(model2).to receive(:value).and_return 99
  # next line fails because it returns 100. when fetched, model2.value = 0
  expect(model.subtract_last_model).to eq 1
end

# Model
def subtract_last_model
 value - Model.last.value
end
```

I need to be able to stub `model2` aka `Model.last` to return 99.

I could, of course, write the following and then write a spec to see if this was called with the correct params, but I was curious if there was another way:

```
def subtract_model(model)
  value - model.value
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It' easy, just stub `Model` with `model2`:

```
it 'does something' do
  allow(model).to receive(:value).and_return 100
  model2 = FactoryGirl.create :model

  #  stub Model
  allow(Model).to receive(:last).and_return model2
  allow(model2).to receive(:value).and_return 99

  # next line fails because it returns 100. when fetched, model2.value = 0
  expect(model.subtract_last_model).to eq 1
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`Model.last` does not return the stubbed `model2`, but reloads an unstubbed version of `model2` from the database. Therefore:

```
it 'does something' do
  allow(model).to receive(:value).and_return 100
  model2 = FactoryGirl.create :model
  allow(model2).to receive(:value).and_return 99

  allow(Model).to receive(:last).and_return(model2)

  expect(model.subtract_last_model).to eq 1
end
```